# Productivity Power Tools 2015 - Custom PeekF1

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, reference

I'm trying to get Productivity Power Tools 2015 - PeekF1, once activated to work with a custom search engine/my own webpage. As it is known, when one highlights a certain keyword and press ALT+F1, it'll open a small window, already directing to Microsoft's page and definition.

What I'm trying to do is the same except, with my own site and certain keywords that C#/VS's Library doesn't have.

I was wondering how do I go about it and if it was possible to add a reference in here.

[image]